# Setting textbox value in modal window using onclick button using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I ma trying to display username in modal text box using onclick button
I have a button from there on `onclick` i am calling `onclick="getUserName(this.id)"`

```
this.id
```

gives me name which i want to set in

```
modal textbox userName
```

**Here is my function**

```
function getUserName(username) {
      $('#editUserPopUp').bind('show',function(){
          alert(username);
          $("#userName").val(username);
      });
 }
```

I am getting username in `alert(username)`
but how do i set thsi value to my modal, username text field

**Here is my Modal**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id=editUserPopUp tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Password</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                                                                                    
        <form class="EditUserBody" role="form" id="usermanagement_editUser="novalidate" method="POST">
          <div class="input-group col-md-8">
           <span class="input-group-addon">User Name</span>
             <input class="form-control" id="userName" type="text" class="input-medium" disabled />
          </div>           
        </form> 
       </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the button in your code?

Comment: Take a look here [http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Answer (score 3):

This should work.

But you should also take a look at the Bootstrap documentation about modal windows. There is a section explaining how to vary modal content.

[**Varying modal content based on trigger button**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

> Use event.relatedTarget and HTML data-* attributes (possibly via jQuery) to vary the contents of the modal depending on which button was clicked.

```js
function getUserName(username) {
  var $modal = $('#editUserPopUp'),
      $userName = $modal.find('#userName');
  $userName.val(username);
  $modal.modal("show");
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="getUserName(this.id)" id="Foo Bar">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id=editUserPopUp tabindex="-1" 
    role="dialog" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Password</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                                                                                    
        <form class="EditUserBody" role="form" id="usermanagement_editUser="novalidate" method="POST">
          <div class="input-group col-md-8">
           <span class="input-group-addon">User Name</span>
             <input class="form-control" id="userName" type="text" class="input-medium" disabled />
          </div>           
        </form> 
       </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you are using `show` event,instead try call `shown` event after all, like so :

```
function getUserName(username) {
  $('#editUserPopUp').modal('show');

  $('#editUserPopUp').on('shown', function () {
    alert(username);
    $("#userName").val(username);
  })

}
```

p/s : did't test it. Hope this help. Comment if did't work.

Comment: @varun what version did you used for bootstrap?

Comment: Try change `shown` event into `shown.bs.modal`, i'm facing this problem before but able to solve that by doing something like this. Chek here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events